# Failing to upload a file using Apollo Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, apollo, apollo-client

#### Problem description

I am trying to upload an image using an upload mutation as explained [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/advanced/upload)

but I am always receiving from the server

`{"statusCode":500,"code":"ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE","error":"Internal Server Error","message":"The \"string\" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or ArrayBuffer. Received an instance of Object"}`

I am using apollo version **3.7.1**

#### Code and logs

Here is the kotlin code for making the request

```
val file = File(filePath)
val upload = DefaultUpload.Builder().fileName(file.name).content(file).build()
val response = apolloClient.mutation(UploadAvatarMutation(file = upload)).execute()
```

##### NB:

In the code above I couldn't resolve `File.toUpload()` as mentioned in the [doc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/advanced/upload)

##### The request:

```
--> POST https://api.goling.com/v1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=0cabe113-64eb-4785-a60a-7a0b1fd1e23f
Content-Length: 701
X-APOLLO-OPERATION-ID: e3250dbd528eb9c0628768ad0a565706bfc9c5f5d5ad9036df2a73dbc20ea6f4
X-APOLLO-OPERATION-NAME: UploadAvatar
20Accept: multipart/mixed; deferSpec=20220824, application/json
 --> END POST (one-shot body omitted)
```

##### The response:

```
<-- 500 https://api.goling.com/v1 (256ms)
date: Sat, 19 Nov 2022 13:18:02 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
cf-ray: 76c93ac00ecc5fbe-MRS
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
vary: Accept-Encoding
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
access-control-allow-credentials: true
content-security-policy: default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';font-src 'self' https: data:;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests
cross-origin-embedder-policy: require-corp
cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin
cross-origin-resource-policy: same-origin
 origin-agent-cluster: ?1
referrer-policy: no-referrer
 x-content-type-options: nosniff
 x-dns-prefetch-control: off
 x-download-options: noopen
 x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: none
x-xss-protection: 0
server: cloudflare
 alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
{"statusCode":500,"code":"ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE","error":"Internal Server Error","message":"The \"string\" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or ArrayBuffer. Received an instance of Object"}
 <-- END HTTP (211-byte body)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the `File.toUpload()` from the document use your `val file = File(filePath)` like this:

```
val file = File(filePath)
file.toUpload(...)
```